# How to skip baseline in equations?

Tags: spacing, matrices

I used the following code to resemble the formula on the right hand side of the picture, but I get the left hand side in which the columnar matrix is too tall!

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2.2} 
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\sign}{\operatorname{sign}}
\newcommand{\ub}[2]{\underbrace{#1}_{#2}}
\newcommand{\x}{\textsc {x}}
\newcommand{\z}{\textsc {z}}
\newcommand{\w}{\textsc {w}}
\newcommand{\wmad}[1]{\tilde{w}_{#1}}
\newcommand{\hx}{h{(\x)}}
\begin{align*}
\hx &= \sign \left( \ub{-0.6}{\wmad{0}} \cdot \ub{1}{z_0} + \ub{1}{\wmad{1}} \cdot \ub{x_1^2}{z_1} + \ub{1}{\wmad{2}} \cdot \ub{x_2^2}{z_2}  \right) \\
&= \sign \left( \ub{[\wmad{0},\wmad{1},\wmad{2}] }{\tilde{\w}^{\scriptscriptstyle \mathrm{T}}}
\ub{
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\ z_1 \\ z_2
    \end{bmatrix}}{\z}
\right)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

if I remove the `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2.2}` I get a better result, but I need to keep it for adjusting the distance between lines of text.

Comment: I suppose you mean the *left* hand side matrix is too tall?

Comment: @Bernard sorry, right! left.

Comment: Plase, complete your MWE. There are nod defined commands and functions ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See, if this is what you looking for:

[image]

The code of above equations is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2.2}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\sign}{\operatorname{sign}}
\newcommand{\ub}[2]{\underbrace{#1}_{#2}}
\newcommand{\x}{\textsc {x}}
\newcommand{\z}{\textsc {z}}
\newcommand{\w}{\textsc {w}}
\newcommand{\wmad}[1]{\tilde{w}_{#1}}
\newcommand{\hx}{h{(\x)}}

\setlength\arraycolsep{1pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.4}

    \begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{align*}
\hx &= \sign\left(\begin{array}{c}
            \ub{-0.6}{\wmad{0}}\cdot \ub{1}{z_0} + \ub{1}{\wmad{1}}\cdot \ub{x_1^2}{z_1} + \ub{1}{\wmad{2}} \cdot \ub{x_2^2}{z_2}
            \end{array}\right)  \\
    &= \sign\left(\begin{array}{rl}
            \ub{[\wmad{0},\wmad{1},\wmad{2}]}{\tilde{\w}^{\mathrm{T}}}
           &
    \ub{\begin{bmatrix}
        1 \\z_1 \\ z_2
        \end{bmatrix}}{\z}
            \end{array}\right)
\end{align*}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: sorry, just I already did (before your answer), please review the question!

Comment: After your editing of question the situation is complete changed. Now your question title seems to be misleading. You like to change baselines skip in equations ...

Comment: Right that is, and I changed the title

Comment: I adopt my answer to your last changes in question. See, if now provide what you like to have.

Comment: Thank you very much, it seems working, I just wait to get sure before accepting your answer!